# How do I transform my html tags to blocks from a dictionary with python?(web-scraping with bs4)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was scraping the contents from a webpage but it got difficult at the description part, here is the website:

https://web.archive.org/web/20200518073855/https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/best-movies-2/

Here's my code:

```
# Imports

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import *

# Flask

from flask import Flask, render_template

# Scraper

URL = "https://web.archive.org/web/20200518073855/https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/best-movies-2/"
res = get(URL)
html_data = res.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')
film_data = soup.find_all(name='div', class_='article-title-description__text')

total_films = []

for film in film_data:
    name = str(film.find('h3', class_='title')).split(')')[-1].split(':')[-1].split('</h3>')[0]
    year = str(film.find('strong')).split('<strong>')[-1].split('</strong>')[0]
    image= film.find('img', class_='landscape')
    # print(image)
    desc = film.findChildren('p')
    for strong_tag in desc[1].find_all('a'):
        desc__txt = strong_tag.text, strong_tag.next_sibling
    new_obj = {
        "name": name,
        "year": year,
        'image': image,
        "desc": desc
    }
    total_films.append(new_obj)

# Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def show_data():
    return render_template('index.html', total_films=total_films)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5100)
```

and here is what I get:

```
    <h1>Movie Scraper</h1>
    <h1>Stand By Me</h1>
    <h2>1986</h2>
    [<p class="description"><p><strong>1986</strong><br/><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20200518073855/https://www.empireonline.com/people/rob-reiner/">Rob Reiner</a>'s adaptation of <a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20200518073855/https://www.empireonline.com/people/stephen-king/">Stephen King</a>'s novella The Body is a stirring, touching adventure film which knows the real world is exciting and scary enough just as it is. It's also a coming-of-age movie which celebrates the intensity of childhood friendship, while gently mourning the transience of such bonds. Which is why, unlike its central character, it'll never get old.<br/><br/><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20200518073855/https://www.empireonline.com/movies/reviews/stand-review/">Read Empire's review of Stand By Me</a><br/><a class="amazon-link" href="https://web.archive.org/web/20200518073855/https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003BNY6YE/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&amp;tag=baucitnet-21&amp;camp=1634&amp;creative=6738&amp;linkCode=as2&amp;creativeASIN=B003BNY6YE&amp;linkId=5dd32860f2c5126a8a53f2668f114778" rel="nofollow">Buy the film now</a><br/></p> </p>, <p><strong>1986</strong><br/><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20200518073855/https://www.empireonline.com/people/rob-reiner/">Rob Reiner</a>'s adaptation of <a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20200518073855/https://www.empireonline.com/people/stephen-king/">Stephen King</a>'s novella The Body is a stirring, touching adventure film which knows the real world is exciting and scary enough just as it is. It's also a coming-of-age movie which celebrates the intensity of childhood friendship, while gently mourning the transience of such bonds. Which is why, unlike its central character, it'll never get old.<br/><br/><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20200518073855/https://www.empireonline.com/movies/reviews/stand-review/">Read Empire's review of Stand By Me</a><br/><a class="amazon-link" href="https://web.archive.org/web/20200518073855/https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003BNY6YE/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&amp;tag=baucitnet-21&amp;camp=1634&amp;creative=6738&amp;linkCode=as2&amp;creativeASIN=B003BNY6YE&amp;linkId=5dd32860f2c5126a8a53f2668f114778" rel="nofollow">Buy the film now</a><br/></p>]
```

I tried using the flask CKEditor but it didn't really help. I was expecting the authors to at least use a class but the part that I need only contains sibling and a parent(that has a class).

Answer (score 0):

A due explanation is probably needed: I wanted to provide you a minimum reproducible chunk of code, so that you could verify its inner workings and then readapt yours to extract as many movies' data you wish.

For this purpose, instead of making a request and getting the entire HTML of the page, I have copied a small subset of it.

What you can see is that I merely used some regex to remove the number on the chart followed by ")" in the name, the year is casted to an integer, the description adopts again a little regex to remove the first characters we get (they contained the year), the image is extracted roughly in the same way as you did. And then, I add this information to my lists at the end of the for loop. Finally, after having finished looping, we assign the lists to our dictionary.

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """ <section class="gallery__content-item gallery__content-item--gallery" data-slide-pos="1"><div class="gallery__content-item__item-wrapper"><div class="static-image"><div class="static-image__primary-next gallery__overlay--trigger hide " data-article-gallery-overlay="article-gallery-overlay"><img class="gallery-icon" src="/web/20200518073855im_/https://www.empireonline.com/assets-legacy/img/icons/gallery-icon.svg"><div class="static-image__primary-next__details"><span class="static-image__primary-next__view-gallery">View Gallery</span><span class="static-image__primary-next__image-count">100 photos</span></div><img class="gallery-arrow" src="/web/20200518073855im_/https://www.empireonline.com/assets-legacy/img/icons/gallery-cover-arrow-right.svg"></div><div class="static-image__primary-total">2 of 100</div><picture><source media="(max-width: 439px)" srcset="//web.archive.org/web/20200518073855im_/https://cdn.onebauer.media/one/media/5d2d/d990/853e/7cd6/60cc/fa2e/raging-bull.jpg?quality=50&amp;width=700&amp;ratio=1-1&amp;resizeStyle=aspectfit&amp;format=jpg"><img class="landscape" src="//web.archive.org/web/20200518073855im_/https://cdn.onebauer.media/one/media/5d2d/d990/853e/7cd6/60cc/fa2e/raging-bull.jpg?quality=50&amp;width=900&amp;ratio=1-1&amp;resizeStyle=aspectfit&amp;format=jpg" alt="Raging Bull" title="99) Raging Bull"></picture></div></div><div class="article-title-description"><div class="article-title-description__text"><h3 class="title">99) Raging Bull</h3><div class="descriptionWrapper"><p class="description"></p><p><strong>1980</strong><br><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20200518073855/https://www.empireonline.com/people/martin-scorsese/">Martin Scorsese</a> and <a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20200518073855/https://www.empireonline.com/people/robert-de-niro/">Robert De Niro</a> have together made movies better than their boxing biopic, but it's hard to argue that any of those movies feature a more jaw-dropping performance than De Niro's here as self-destructive pugilist Jake La Motta. It also features some of cinema's best-shot fights; hard to believe that before Scorsese, no director thought to put the camera inside the ring...<br><br><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20200518073855/https://www.empireonline.com/movies/raging-bull/">Read Empire's review of Raging Bull</a><br><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20200518073855/https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B004G8QT2U/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&amp;tag=baucitnet-21&amp;camp=1634&amp;creative=6738&amp;linkCode=as2&amp;creativeASIN=B004G8QT2U&amp;linkId=b26f7fb5172ea177d53f358d272209a3" rel="nofollow" class="amazon-link">Buy the film now</a><br></p>
<p></p></div></div></div></section> """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='article-title-description__text')

names = []
years = []
descriptions = []
images = []

# Extract the text from each div and print it
for div in divs:
    name = re.sub(r'^\d+\)\s*', '', soup.find('h3', class_='title').text)
    year = int(soup.find('strong').text)
    description = re.sub(r'^\w{4}', '', soup.find('div', class_='descriptionWrapper').text.strip())
    img = soup.find('img', {'class': 'landscape'})
    src = img['src']
    names.append(name)
    years.append(year)
    descriptions.append(description)
    images.append(src)

# Create a dictionary of the lists and print it
mydict = {'name': names, 'year': years, 'description': descriptions, 'image': images}
print(mydict)
```

You can then expect your dictionary to look roughly like this.

```json
{
   "name":[
      "Raging Bull"
   ],
   "year":[
      1980
   ],
   "description":[
      "Martin Scorsese and Robert De Niro have together made movies better than their boxing biopic, but it's hard to argue that any of those movies feature a more jaw-dropping performance than De Niro's here as self-destructive pugilist Jake La Motta. It also features some of cinema's best-shot fights; hard to believe that before Scorsese, no director thought to put the camera inside the ring...Read Empire's review of Raging BullBuy the film now"
   ],
   "image":[
      "//web.archive.org/web/20200518073855im_/https://cdn.onebauer.media/one/media/5d2d/d990/853e/7cd6/60cc/fa2e/raging-bull.jpg?quality=50&width=900&ratio=1-1&resizeStyle=aspectfit&format=jpg"
   ]
}
```